# Diff between a string and a file

Tags: diff, here-document, here-string

Basically I want to check the difference of the same file before and after a `sed`

Tried to run:

```
diff /opt/postTrades.sh <<< $(sed 's/1\ MIN/10\ MIN/g' /opt/postTrades.sh)
```

and

```
diff <<< $(sed 's/1\ MIN/10\ MIN/g' /opt/postTrades.sh) < /opt/postTrades.sh
```

and

```
diff <<< (sed 's/1\ MIN/10\ MIN/g' /opt/postTrades.sh) < /opt/postTrades.sh
```

Always getting:

```
diff: missing operand after '/opt/postTrades.sh'
diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.
```

What's the correct way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`diff` needs two file operands.  With a here-string, you pass input to `diff` on its standard input.

To make `diff` read from standard input, use `-` as the filename:

```
$ diff file - <<<"$( sed 'expression' file )"
```

or, more portably,

```
$ sed 'expression' file | diff file -
```

If you are using a shell that supports process substitutions with `<(...)`, like `bash` and `ksh93`, this may be another solution:

```
$ diff file <( sed 'expression' file )
```

The process substitution will show up as a file to `diff` and is virtually "the same as":

```
$ sed 'expression' file >tempfile
$ diff file tempfile
$ rm tempfile
```

Comment: is `<( expression )` a diff syntax? because I saw it's space sensitive and I don't know of any other place this syntax is used. @Kusalananda

Comment: @Moshe It is part of the shell syntax. It is not specific to `diff` in any way. It is not portable between shells, so it's only used when one knows that the current shell supports it. Look for "process substitution" in your shell's manual.